# Formatting disappears when adding variable to URL

Tags: php

I have a website that operates using PHP. On the website you should be able to order food.
For example, it says "McDonalds" as a link and when you press that link it should take you to another php file. I am using the standard HTML "a href". Everything works fine. However, I want to able to know that the user clicked McDonalds and not another restaurant name subway. As a result, I need a way to transfer that information to the next php file. Currently, I am putting the name into the URL. So the URL looks something like this: , where {$position["name"]} is equal to McDonalds. Now, in the browser of the next page I can actually see my domain name followed by order.php, which is the file name, followed by /?name=McDonalds. However, all the formatting disappears. Furthermore, in the next file, order.php, I have another link for the user to order the food:  . Here I transfer the name of the restaurant and the name of the food. When I click that one, instead of taking me to process.php, it takes me to order.php/process.php. So basically it is the same page order.php and not process.php. And of course the formatting disappears. When I try to navigate between my webpages and files without this "/?name=something " part, the formatting is fine. The only thing is that I can then not transfer information anymore.

OK sorry for this question. The coherence really suffers, but I just don't know how I can phrase my problem correctly. Anyways, I guess there are two overall questions in this post: How would I solve the above problem? And is there another way to transfer variables between files? This would get rid of the above problem. But remember, it is not just any variable. It should be through a link that determines what variable is transferred. If the user clicks "Subway", $name="Subway" should be transferred; if he clicks "McDonalds", $name="McDonalds" should be transferred.

Lastly, I am sure that the problem makes more sense, if you actually look at my website. So I guess if interested, I will share the URL of my website with you, so that you can take a closer look.

```
<table border= 0px dashed black style="width:100%">
<?php
    print("<tr>");
       print("<td><a href='about.php'>   Über Proton    </a> </td>");
       print("<td><a href='contact.php'>  Kontakt    </a>   </td>");
       print("<td><a href='logout.php'>  Log Out    </a>  </td>");
    print("</tr>");

    ?>

</table>


     <div id="text" style="background-image: url(http://www.revolutionspeaks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Light-Blue-Background-top-header-1024x320.jpg); border: 1px solid green; border-radius: 5px; padding: 20px; margin: 20px;">

          <h4 style="font-family: Calibri; padding 10px;"> Hier können sie eine Liste von Restaurants sehen. Bitte auf das jeweilige Restaurant klicken, um die Menükarte zu sehen. Klicken sie zu jeder Zeit auf das Pronto Logo oben, um wieder hier zurück zur Homepage zu gelangen.
           </h4>
           </div>

<table border= 2px dashed black style="width:100%">
   <?php


    print("<tr style='color: green;'>");
       print("<td><strong>   Restaurant         </strong></td>");
       print("<td><strong>   Addresse     </strong></td>");
    print("</tr>");

    print("<tr>");
      foreach ($positions as $position){
        print("<tr>");
        print("<td><a href='order.php/?name={$position["name"]}'>   {$position["name"]}        </a> </td>");
        print("<td>   {$position["address"]}        </td>"); 
        print("</tr>");
      }
   ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You might be looking for $_POST and $_GET, see here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php and http://it1.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: yeah I'm using $_GET right now

Comment: You should just share some code, than we can see what is wrong

Comment: Would you mind looking at my website, it might be easier

Comment: I don't mind, but that won't have an effort. It's really hard to tell without code

Comment: OK I posted the code above. Some text is in German sorry. So basically I want to transmit $position["name"] to order.php, when $position["name"] is clicked. Is there any other way to do that except for the method I did.

Comment: Looks like your best bet would be to [Read The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: I have already read it multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put double quotes inside double quotes. That won't work. do this instead:

```
print("<td><a href='order.php/?name={$position['name']}'>   {$position['name']}        </a> </td>");
print("<td>   {$position['address']}        </td>");
```